# Foundation Healthcheck: How to check if Foundation loaded properly in a page?

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

I want to use Foundation in a web framework. I did the following:

1. Included all the dependencies (modernizr, fastclick, jQuery), as well as Foundation's `min.js` and `.css` file.
2. Added the following script; before the end of the `</body>` tag :

   $(document).foundation();

If I load the page, on the style level, looks to be Foundation, however the Foundation's features; does not seems to work (modal, top-bar, etc.). I double check the generated source code for the page and all the script and style sheets are available.

So the question is, how to debug the loading of the Foundation in a page? What parameters do I need to look at?